# JOLT: Transforming comma separated value to object

Tags: java, transformation, jolt

can someone help with jolt spec .

**input** :

> ```
> {
>  "data": [
>      {
>      "key": "A,B,C,D,S"
>      }
>   ]
> }
> ```

I want output like :

```
{
 "id":"A"
},
{
 "id":"B"
},
{
 "id":"C"
},
{
 "id":"D"
},
{
 "id":"S"
}
```

The key can be of n numbers of commaSeperated value . and I need n number of objects

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only with Jolt 0.1.1 which has a "split" function.   However at this time the Jolt Demo site has not been updated to use it.

https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases/tag/jolt-0.1.1

"split" unit test

https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/7812399d1c955742d81eae363244a2d0ef86cf3b/jolt-core/src/test/resources/json/modifier/functions/stringsSplitTest.json